# Logging Bad Sectors

Tags: hard-drive, log

Is there a program that will maintain a log of growing bad sectors?
I want to measure the regression of my hard drive automatically as opposed to manually taking [screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5m8M.png).

**UPDATE:**
After running `sudo badblocks /dev/sda | wc -l >> num_bad_blocks.log` and allowing it to run over night, the file reported I have zero bad blocks. How could there be such a vast difference?

Comment: What is the output of `sudo badblocks /dev/sda` then?

Comment: I run `sudo badblocks -sv /dev/sda | wc -l >> num_bad_blocks.log` and wait an approximate 2 hours before completion. Upon returning to my computer the terminal is closed and `num_bad_blocks.log` simply states 0.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1446132/612958

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to replace your hard drive if you have 300,000+ bad sectors.

However, you should be able to accomplish this by periodically running

```
sudo badblocks /dev/sda | wc -l >> num_bad_blocks.log
```

which should total up the number of bad blocks and append that number to a file. You could run this regularly with a cron job.