# Is 7 bad sectors acceptable?

Tags: hard-drive

new Ubuntu user here.

**Disk is OK, 7 bad sectors (37° C/99° F)**

My laptop is 6 years old, and the fan was getting really noisy (I suspect it was because the laptop couldn't really handle the Windows 10 1806 update), so I switched to Ubuntu and it's gone mostly quiet.
It's a 1TB HDD, has never been touched, added to, or subtracted from, currently 6.3% full. The laptop is a Samsung and I suspect the HDD is a Samsung too.

1. Do most HDDs have zero bad sectors?
2. At how many bad sectors should I be looking to change my laptop/HDD?
   (I back up regularly, nothing really important on this laptop)

Thank you

Comment: 7 bad sectors isn't bad... depending on WHERE they are, and IF they are causing the drive to do re-calibrates.  If you don't notice a problem, then you're fine.

Comment: Read this: [Bad Sectors Explained - How-To Geek](https://www.howtogeek.com/173463/bad-sectors-explained-why-hard-drives-get-bad-sectors-and-what-you-can-do-about-it/)

Comment: As long as the SMART status is fine and the number of bad sectors is not significantly increasing, your disk is probably still rather safely usable for another while. Just make sure you regularly check back on the value every now and then and stay aware of the fact that the disk *could* possibly die some time (which is always the case, even for brand new disks)...

Comment: The edit deleted the part about the fan making a lot of noise. So an answer on that part now looks kind of ridiculous, although it wasn't. Not a good edit.

Answer (score 1):

It is not that bad, but having even one bad sector is a warning sign that the part has entered the next failure stage, and more bad sectors can develop. It is just a matter of how soon. So, definitely don't rely on this system for important work/data you plan on preserving.

Also, the hdd does not require a fixed number of bad sectors to die suddenly (the chance of sudden death already increased significantly between zero to non-zero), so the usual recommended practice is to get a replacement for any hard disk with known bad sectors.

Answer (score 1):

If

1. the number of bad sectors does not increase rapidly
2. the smart status of the drive is still ok
3. the sectors are located more to the inside of the platter(s) in the
   drive ( so it doesn't disrupt your OS )

you are kind of safe.

That said though, if you still run an HDD, it is advisable to replace it with a SSD. Your laptop will be so much quicker by doing this. The size of the SSD depends on your budget. You can put your HDD in an external USB 3.0 case to still use it for data.

Always make backups (means more than 1 ) to another medium ( hdd, ssd, usb device, sd card ).

About the fan:
It can get noisy due to dust build up in the cooling system ( it would not be as efficient as without dust, so the fan has to work harder to keep CPU and GPU cool ) or on the fan itself. 
The latter will effect the balance of the fan, so it will put more strain on the bearing. Which on its turn shortens the lifespan of the fan. 
Clean it with a soft brush and a can of compressed air. When doing this on the fan, stop it from spinning around with your finger. 
If after cleaning the fan is still noisy the cause is a worn out bearing. You should replace the fan. 
For a laptop fan look at the serial number ( hope it has one ) and it is typically harder to replace than in a desktop computer ( not only technically, but due to availability as well).

Comment: About the fan: That whole section was edited out. It was to be found another question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Disk Genius](https://www.diskgenius.com/) program to scan and remove bad sectors, it's not always the hard disk that need to replace, you maybe only need to change SATA cable , then the sectors will stop appear
to run the program you will need to make the hard disk as a slave on a running device, or you can use [Hiren's BootCD](https://www.hirensbootcd.org/) after you burn it on a CD or make boot able USB on a flash memory.

Note:
1-The bad sectors often will cause not responding and system failure.

2- before you remove the sectors backup your important files to another disk.

3- After remove it by Disk Genius you will need to repair Ubuntu using `fsck /dev/sda2` command by a live CD or in the black screen if it appear command port option , while sda2 is the system partition at you maybe will other number, any way only system can be fix by this command, for Microsoft operation system you maybe need to install a new one but try system repair option first.

**Note:** If the hard has physical damage new bad sectors will appear again on the running area, so you will need to get another healthy hard disk.

Comment: Does "disk genius" work on Linux? Website says it's a .exe

Comment: No , I tried to run it using Wine HQ but it didn't work, so the best way to run it is by using Hiren's BootCD, or if you have a device working by Microsoft operation system you can connect the infected hard as a slave and run Disk Genius direct to fix the hard disk, the last Version of Hiren's BootCD has the last Disk Genius version till now so you will not need to download it , and anyway it's size about 50 megabytes and you can find portable version.

Comment: Anyway to try to fix any bad sectors you will need to run a live CD to can write on system partition , and the Hiren's Boot CD is a live CD that running now using windows 10 MS OS , so you can run the program using it, just burn it on  CD or boot able on flash memory as I said above.

Answer (score 0):

Your system may continue to operate properly, but some very useful tools such as Clonezilla may refuse to operate on the damaged disk. This can cause you major difficulties if you get into a situation where you need to use them - as, for example, moving to a new disk. I ran into this with a home server install that developed bad sectors on the disk holding the system partition.