# The bad sectors amount has been going up a lot

Tags: hard-drive

I currently have 928 bad sectors and it's been increasing by the minute, but aside from the bad sectors count increasing at an incredible amount, there is no other sign that my hdd is failing, no weird sounds, no freezing, no slowing down, any help?
EDIT: Here's a smart log.
https://pastebin.com/dzrjakAQ

Comment: A small chance that something is wonky and giving bad results.  Would make sure to have new hard drive and backup important data now, before testing.

Comment: Can see this link for more info.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1041018/is-7-bad-sectors-acceptable?rq=1  Would get all important data onto another drive as soon as possible.  Hard drives cheap, non replaceable data/photos priceless.

Answer (score 0):

What Crip650 said in his comment.  Your device is dying. Backup any irreplacable data onto another device as soon as possible and replace the device at the first  opportunity.